# How to put the indicator arrow icon to the left side of the drawer?

Tags: android

[image]

This is the part that helps the animation of the arrows happen but i want it to be moved to the other side and do the same.

drawable/group_indicator.xml

```
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" android:state_empty="true"></item>
    
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
    
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"></item>

    </selector>
```

list_group.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/dodo">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textColor="#3949AB"
    android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```